# Var[A+B+C] = Var [A] + Var [B] + Var [C]

Tags: probability, variance

I know that this relationship is correct when A,B and C are pairwise independent. However, I'm finding it difficult to calculate it. 
Let's say that: Var [A] = Var [B] = Var [C] = 0.25.
How can I prove that Var[A+B+C] = 0.75?

I started to work with the formula:
Var[A+B+C] =E[(A+B+C)^2]−(E[A+B+C])^2 but I got stuck.

Thanks!

Comment: Compute $E(A+B+C)^2=E(A^2+B^2+C^2+2AB+2AC+2BC)$, note $E(AB)=E(A)E(B)$, etc.

Comment: Thanks, can you please elaborate why should i do it like that? When you write A^2, do you mean E[A] or Var[A]?

Comment: Adding on to @YuDing's comment, we have e.g. $\mathbb E[AB] = \mathbb E[A]\mathbb E[B]$ due to independence.

Comment: Thanks @ Yu Ding and @Math1000. Let's say E()=E()=E() = 0.5. We have (++)^2 = 0.5^2+0.5^2+0.5^2 + 2*0.25 + 2*0.25 + 2.0.25 = 2.25. And we have (E[A+B+C])^2 = 1.25^2 = 2.25. The variance is 2.25-2.25=0. What am I missing here?

Comment: Your mistake is coming from the fact that you are using $E(A^2) = E(A)^2$, which is not true (since $A$ and $A$ are not independent!)

Comment: @caldar, Thanks but I'm still not sure where is the mistake. Can you please guide me?

Comment: @Calder Also note that if $\mathbb E[A^2]=\mathbb E[A]^2$ would imply that $\mathrm{var}(A)=0$, so that $A$ is degenerate (there is some point $c$ such that $\mathbb P(A=c)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Expand your formula, using the fact that for pairwise independent random variables $X$ and $Y$, we have $E(XY) = E(X)E(Y)$:
\begin{align*}
\text{Var}(A + B + C) & = E((A + B + C)^2) - (E(A + B + C))^2\\
& = E(A^2) + E(B^2) + E(C^2) + 2E(AB) + 2E(AC) + 2E(BC)\\
& \quad - E(A)^2 - E(B)^2 -E(C)^2 - 2E(A)E(B) + 2E(A)E(C) + 2E(B)E(C)\\
& = E(A^2) + E(B^2) + E(C^2) + 2E(A)E(B) + 2E(A)E(C) + 2E(B)E(C)\\
& \quad - E(A)^2 - E(B)^2 -E(C)^2 - 2E(A)E(B) + 2E(A)E(C) + 2E(B)E(C)\\
& = (E(A^2) - E(A)^2) + (E(B^2) - E(B)^2) + (E(C^2) - E(C)^2)\\
& = \text{Var}(A) + \text{Var}(B) + \text{Var}(C).
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

First notice (using the fact that $A$, $B$ and $C$ are pairwise independent) that $C$ is independent to $A+B$ :

\begin{align*}
E((A+B)C) &= E(AC+BC) \\
&= E(AC)+E(BC) \\
&= E(A)E(C)+E(B)E(C) \\
&= (E(A)+E(B))E(C)\\
&= E(A+B)E(C).
\end{align*}

Then one has

\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Var}(A+B+C) &= \operatorname{Var}(A+B)+\operatorname{Var}(C) \\
&=\operatorname{Var}(A)+\operatorname{Var}(B)+\operatorname{Var}(C). 
\end{align*}